# Make the soft gradient between colors of LinearGradient removed

Tags: swiftui, linear-gradients

Let's say I have a LinearGradient of 3 colors Red, Blue, and Green.

Can we possibly make the soft gradient between these 3 colors removed? I am trying to animate between hard and soft gradient of LinearGradient.

Something like this:

```
LinearGradient(colors: [.red, .blue, .green], startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .leading)
```

what i have:
[image]

what i want it to be when some condition is met:
[image]

Comment: I'm uncertain about your terminology... would you elaborate more what do you mean by soft vs hard ... and provide example of code how do you that.

Comment: Thanks for correction. I have made an edit to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LinearGradient(stops: ) init. It will not give you a full hard edge, but quite close. You can then change the stop values or the array for animation.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let stops = [Gradient.Stop(color: Color.green, location: 0.0),
                 Gradient.Stop(color: Color.green, location: 0.33),
                 Gradient.Stop(color: Color.blue, location: 0.33),
                 Gradient.Stop(color: Color.blue, location: 0.66),
                 Gradient.Stop(color: Color.red, location: 0.66),
                 Gradient.Stop(color: Color.red, location: 1.0)]

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(
                LinearGradient(stops: stops, startPoint: .trailing, endPoint: .leading)
            )
            .frame(height: 200)
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool approach. I take that.

Answer (score 1):

There is an other way for getting same result with less and more easier way, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HorizontalQuantumLinearGradientView(colors: [.red, .blue, .green])
    }
}

struct HorizontalQuantumLinearGradientView: View {
    let colors: [Color]
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: .zero) {
            ForEach(colors, id:\.self) { item in item }
        }
    }
}

struct VerticalQuantumLinearGradientView: View {
    let colors: [Color]
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            ForEach(colors, id:\.self) { item in item }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is some dark magic code =)

Comment: @Carrot: Thanks, happy to be able help you. ;)